# How can I Disable an element when URL contains a specific string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogspot

```html
 <div class="test-class">
    <div class="test-class1" id="test-id1">hello 1</div>
     <div class="test-class2" id="test-id2">hello 2</div>             
    <div class="test-class3" id="test-id3">hello 3</div>
  </div>
```

And I would like to Disable/hide the Second [div] (id="test-id2") , when the page URL contains the string ?fullpost.

So for example: if my URL is `http://www.example.com/post_1.html?fullpost` then `test-id2 div` should not be active.

And if the URL is for example only `http://www.example.com/post_1.html` then `test-id2 div` should be active.

```js
<script>
let element = document.getElementById("test-id2");

if(window.location.href.search("?fullpost") > -1){
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
```

My script is not working.

Comment: Why use `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` instead of `element.remove()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<script>
  let element = document.getElementById("test-id2");

  if(window.location.href.includes("?fullpost")){
     element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use indexOf() instead of search ()

```
let element = document.getElementById("test-id2");
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("?fullpost") > -1) 
{ 
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using Regex check the next code

```
var element = document.getElementById("test-id2");
var reg = /(\?|\&)?fullpost/g;
var url = window.location.href;
if (reg.exec(url) !== null) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Here's the full page of the snapshot https://output.jsbin.com/cataxix?fullpost

The regex will check if the URL contains fullpost as the first parameter or wherever it is in the URL as a parameter.
If your URL was like that http://www.example.com/post_1.html?anything&fullpost it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I run it window.location.href.search("?fullpost") naturally gets parsed as a regular expression. So you need to escape the '?'

```
<script>
let element = document.getElementById("test-id2");

if(window.location.href.search("/?fullpost") > -1){
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
```

Another way to do it would be to use includes()

```
if(window.location.href.includes("?fullpost"))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

add a listener on that element -- you want it to prevent only for a specific page

```js
let ELM = document.getElementById("test-id2");
ELM.addEventListener("click",(ev) => {
   if(window.location.href.test(/\?fulpost/)){
     //ev.preventDefault(); // for <a></a>
     ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this will prevent any click_event from execution
   }
},true);
```